# Systemctl restart the `network` fail

Tags: centos, networking, systemd, network-interface

First of all, I am apology for the pictures, because I can not connect to the issue-machine, so I can not copy the code, only can post the photograph.

I use `systemctl restart network`, get fail.

So, I use the `systemctl status network.service -l` to check the error message:

[image]

I use `journalctl -xe` to check error message:

[image]

The `/var/log/message` error log:

[image]

My `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0`:

[image]

This is my network-interfaces:

[image]

I tried add the `HWADDR=00.30.18.14.7b.bb` in my `ifcfg-enp2s0`, but still do not work.

---

**EDIT-1**

This is the `journalctl -u network.service`:

[image]

Comment: For a text form of this question, see the four-year-old question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100588/ .

Comment: OMG - Oh My GNU! Screenshot ... then scp to another computer to make that correct .. or ... scp a text copy ... that is weird!

Comment: @aurelien You know the network-interface is down, I can not connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `ip`, enp2s0 is showing as `NO-CARRIER` (i.e. the cable is not plugged in.) Are you sure that the cable is securely connected and working correctly? DHCP won't try to obtain an address until the interface is fully up, and setting the MAC address isn't usually required (especially if you're setting it to the default value for the card.)

Answer (score 0):

you maybe use the solution according to the following thread

[Centos 7: failed to bring up/down networking: configure interface for a trunk interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220750/centos-7-failed-to-bring-up-down-networking-configure-interface-for-a-trunk-in)

`systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
systemctl start NetworkManager`

Comment: Be careful, this will prevent `NetworkManager` from starting on boot.